# Oracle 12c client install hangs - silent/unattended

Tags: windows, oracle12c

Oracle client sometimes stops/hangs with "Please press Enter to exit" when doing a silent/unattended install. 
Happens on both 12.1.0.2 and 12.2.0.1
Windows Task Manager shows the Java install process using 100% of a core.
One repeatable case is where the Oracle home already has an instance installed.
Command and args used:

```
.\setup.exe -silent -noconsole -waitForCompletion -noconfig -responseFile xxx.rsp
```

Platform Server2008R2

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error with no help from hours of searching the "-nowait" arg prevents "Please press Enter to exit" thereby avoiding the hang/never completes situation. This is despite the fact that logs show install was successful.

Without "-nowait" and no errors (installing to a new/different Oracle home) the installer does not present "Please press Enter to exit" and the installer completes successfully unattended (no interaction required).

Further, even with -nowait specified, a hang occurred when the following error (caused by using a space in folder name for Oracle Home), viewable in C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs as, in my case, oraInstall2018-11-12_08-42-48AM.out

```
[FATAL] [INS-32011] The Oracle home Location that you have specified contains the space character.
```

CAUSE: The string you entered contains the space character.
   ACTION: Please choose a string containing only alphanumeric, and a few additional characters that are allowed for your platform.